# Verilog HDL behavioral coding calling modules for ALU

Tags: overflow, verilog, hdl, alu

This is my first time programming in verilog hdl and I am having trouble figuring out what is wrong with my code. I need to design a simple ALU in behavioral code.

So far I have created a subtractor and adder module.( I need to add more modules but I would like to get these working in the ALU module before I add the others).

I have the following modules in seperate .v files in the same project (pretty sure this is behavioral?):

```
module adder3bit( sum, co, a, b);
parameter n = 2;
output reg [n:0] sum;
output reg co;
input [n:0] a;
input [n:0] b;

always @(a, b)
{co, sum} = a + b;

endmodule


module subtract3bit(diff, bo, a, b);
parameter n = 2;
output reg [n:0] diff;
output reg bo;
input [n:0] a;
input [n:0] b;

always @(a, b)
{bo, diff} = a - b;

endmodule
```

I tested these and see that they are working.

Now I am trying to call them in the main ALU module:

```
module alu( out, overflow, a, b,sel);
input [2:0] a, b;
input sel;
output [2:0] out;
output overflow;
always @(a,b,sel)
begin
if(sel=='b0)
    adder3bit A1(out,overflow,a,b);
if(sel=='b1)
    subtract3bit S1( out, overflow, a, b);
end
endmodule
```

My syntax may be wrong, but it is showing errors. I am just very unfamiliar with verilog. I feel how I first felt with learning C. Help would be much appreciated.

I know it is calling the modules correctly but I think it is something to do with the if statements.

Thank you I hope to learn something new!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you want to call module. Modules are not functions or tasks you cannot call them. What you can and should do with module is instantiate it in another module (in this case ALU module). Modules cannot be instantiated inside procedural blocks (e.x. always in your code). Both adder and subtractor will produce new result on every change of it's inputs so you only need to properly drive input's of this  modules and the read its outputs.

I advice you to declare module's port in a more readable way:

```
module adder3bit #(
    parameter N = 2
) ( 
   output reg [N:0] sum, 
   output reg co,
   input [N:0] a,
   input [N:0] b
);
    always @(a, b)
        {co, sum} = a + b;

endmodule
```

In ALU you can instantiate adder3bit like this:

```
module alu (
    input [2:0] a,
    input [2:0] b,
    input sel,
    output [2:0] out,
    output overflow
)
    localparam SIZE = 3;
    wire [SIZE - 1 : 0] diff;
    wire [SIZE - 1 : 0] sum;
    wire co;
    wire bo;

    adder3bit #( 
       .N(SIZE) 
    ) adder (
       .a(a),
       .b(b),
       .sum(sum),
       .co(co)
    );

    subtract3bit #( 
       .N(SIZE) 
    ) subtractor (
       .a(a),
       .b(b),
       .diff(diff),
       .bo(bo)
    );

    always @(*)
    begin
         if(sel=='b0)
             {out,overflow) = {sum, co};
         if(sel=='b1)
             {out,overflow) = {diff, bo};
    end
endmodule
```

And one more thing, your module has parameters which defines size of it inputs and outputs but it's name suggest that it is fixed to three which can be confusing.

Comment: You use `n` & `N` to identify the same parameter which is illegal; pick one or another. I advise using upper case to identify the parameter, as it is common practice in the industry and several programming languages

Comment: Thank you for your help. So the modules need to be initialized ahead of time. That must mean each time an output of the module in the always block is read, it reads a new input depending on a and b? Also, would it be allowed to use a single out wire instead of declaring two wires, sum and diff?

Comment: Module update it's outputs regardless of reading it. Let's take yours adder, you wrote an always procedure inside it which can be read like this: Every time, when a or b change do operation: `{co, sum} = a + b;`.  You cannot use single wire as both outputs contains valid data all the time.  Verilog is a  Hardware Description Language, it's not like C or other programming languages, it describes hardware. You have created asynchronous adder and subtractor, they always drive their outputs with result of a+b and a-b respectively.

Comment: Thank you!! I feel I'm beginning to understand the language better and am less intimidated by the code. I see now how it's representing the hardware, before I was thinking about it too abstractly. Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You cant instantiate a module inside an always block in verilog. Instead you can change the modules adder3bit and substract3bit into tasks and you can use the code as you have written now.
the solution will be like this

```
task adder3bit;
parameter n = 2;
input [n:0] a;
input [n:0] b;
output reg [n:0] sum;
output reg co;
begin
always @(*) {co, sum} = a + b;
endtask


task subtract3bit;
parameter n = 2;
input [n:0] a;
input [n:0] b;
output reg [n:0] diff;
output reg bo;
begin
always @(*) {bo, diff} = a - b;
endtask

module alu( out, overflow, a, b,sel);
input [2:0] a, b;
input sel;
output [2:0] out;
output overflow;
always @(a,b,sel)
begin
if(sel=='b0)
    adder3bit (a,b,out,overflow);
if(sel=='b1)
    subtract3bit ( a,b,out,overflow);
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Tasks cannot contain `always` blocks and cannot declare `parameter`s.

Comment: I didn't dig down the syntax tree enough to see that parameter is a subset of block_item_declaration, which itself is a subset of tf_item_declaration that is used by task. However in re-reviewing the LRMs I did see that _pure_ Verilog (IEEE 1364) does not support tasks/functions defined outside of a module. It is legal in SystemVerilog (IEEE 1800). All modern Verilog simulators are SystemVerilog simulators, but if compiler flag is set to strict Verilog then a task defined outside of a module should be a compiling error.